# How do I implement firebase using React native?

Tags: firebase, react-native

When I try to use npm install to use firebase with React native, I am getting errors.

Then when I try to use require for the firebase module, it says that the document can't be found.

Is there a way to utilize the firebase API with React native instead?

Comment: Inprove your question posting your install commands, error logs or some other detailed info so we can help you ...

Comment: *[Disclaimer: I work at Firebase]* At the moment you'll need to make some manual changes to Firebase's JavaScript SDK for it to work with React Native. Follow along with other people working on this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aoPNvQQsVUE. Or just keep your eyes out for a release of the Firebase JavaScript SDK: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html

Comment: Version 2.2.5 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK just landed and "Firebase client now works in React Native apps". See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html or get it here: https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.5/firebase.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase uses WebSockets, which currently is not supported by React Native. As of now, there is no good solution to integrate Firebase with React Native.

In lieu of requiring firebase as a module, you can indeed use the firebase API instead. If you were doing a simple get request, your fetch function would look like this:

```
var url = "https://YourDatabaseName.firebaseio.com/some/val.json";  
 fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData);
  })
 .done();
```

For more information, you can check out a blog post I wrote about the topic here:
http://anuj.io/using-firebase-api-with-react/

Comment: React Native actually just released a version that support WebSockets (v. 0.4.4): see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases

Comment: Thanks @anuj this was exactly what I was looking for. Works seemlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase dev here — as of [v0.4.4](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.4.4) of React Native, WebSockets are now supported, and as of version [2.2.5](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html) of Firebase's JS client, we've implemented the integration with React Native. Therefore, Firebase should now work in your React Native app!

There is a known issue with our authentication methods at the moment, but we're working on it.

Let us know if you have any questions!